# select or deselect checkboxes in a parent div

Tags: jquery, html

I am using the jQuery accordion with a group of checkboxes per accordion container. Within each of these, I have 2 buttons (select and deselect) and on click, I want them to only select/deselect all the checkboxes in that specific accordion container. It's very frustrating as I am sure the code is about right, so hopefully someone will spot my stupidity and help a brother out:

#### jQuery:

```js
 // Select all for groups:
   $(".group_buttons").on("click",function() {
       var btn_request = $(this).attr("rel");
       var group = $(this);
       if(btn_request == "add") {
           $(this).parent(".controller_box").find('input:checkbox')
                .attr('checked',true);
       } else {
           $(this).parent(".controller_box").find('input:checkbox')
                .attr('checked', false);
       }
       return false;
   });
```

#### Sample HTML:

```html
  <div class='controller_box'>
       <a href='' rel='add' class='group_buttons'>Select all</a>
       <a href='' rel='rem' class='group_buttons'>Select all</a>
       <input type='checkbox' name='sample1' value=1 />
       <input type='checkbox' name='sample2' value=1 />
  </div>
```

Comment: +1 for "help a brother out" :)

Comment: I've just tried this on JSfiddle and works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/kJ2SQ/ even on IE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `prop()` method:

> The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.

```
$(".group_buttons").on("click",function() {
   var btn_request = $(this).attr("rel");
   if(btn_request == "add") {
       $(this).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
   } else {
       $(this).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
   }
   return false;
});
```

*please note that `:checkbox` selector is [`deprecated`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/).*

---

if `.group_buttons` are generated dynamically you should delegate the `click` event:

```
$("body").on('click', '.group_buttons', function() {
   var btn_request = $(this).attr("rel");
   if(btn_request == "add") {
       $(this).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
   } else {
       $(this).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
   }
   return false;
});
```